# Starting a WiFi scan and blocking the thread until the results are ready

Tags: java, android

My main objective is to write a method in Java that could initiate a WiFi scan, wait for the scan results and return them.

I know that I have to register a `BroadcastReceiver` and wait for Android to broadcast an `Intent` with the scan results. My question is - is it possible to block the thread from the moment I called `startScan()` until the receiver's `onReceive()` method is triggered? I tried using a wait()/notify() pair and using a `CountDownLatch` - both blocked the thread, however onReceive was never called.

EDIT: The whole procedure takes place in a worker thread, I'm not blocking the UI thread.

How can this be done?

Comment: You should not block the ui thread. You'll end up in an app not responding error.

Comment: I never said I'm blocking the UI thread

Comment: Then it is a completely different issue. Can you post the code where you register your br. And the br itself, too? For the "blocking" part maybe a handler is what you need.

Comment: You could just set a boolean flag, and only execute the rest of the code in your thread if you are not waiting for a scan result.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't block the UI thread - ever.  When you do, your device will stop responding, and this is terrible UI.

You can block other operations within your app (but disabling buttons, etc) - but you should never, never block the UI thread (and the OS makes it hard to do so).